# SQL table pulling info

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

I have SQL Car table. it contains some columns: Manufacturers, Model etc. I have a few models of the same Manufacturer, so when i pull the Manufacturers column i get the same Manufacturer name more than one time.

for instance:

> Select * from table-name where name equals "Audi"

How can i get the Manufacturers names without getting the same names over and over again?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will remove any duplicates in the result. If you select more than one field then all fields must be equal to be considered duplicate.

```
select distinct manufacturer from table-name
```

Another way is to use `GROUP BY`. This has the advantage of allowing the use of group functions (`MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT` etc):

```
select manufacturer, count(*) from table-name group by manufacturer
```